# Why this is not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My HTML goes like this

```
<div ng-controller = "AppControl">
   <input type="text" id="nameText" ng-model="yourName" value="{{name}}">
   <h1>You are typing : {{yourName}}</h1>
</div>
```

And JavaScript is here

```
var Application = {};
var App = angular.module('Application', []);
function AppControl($scope){
  $scope.name = "Name";
}
```

My expected result is : "Name" should come in textbox as it was assigned through `$scope`.
As textbox is `model`, so `<h1>` tag should be updated with initial value and should be changed whenever I update it. But When I update it is updating value, but initial value is not coming in text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drop `value="{{name}}"` and assign to your model (e.g. `$scope.yourName= "Name";`). Angular will handle the rest.

```
<div ng-controller="AppControl">
   <input type="text" id="nameText" ng-model="yourName">
   <h1>You are typing : {{yourName}}</h1>
</div>

var Application = {};
var App = angular.module('Application', []);
function AppControl($scope){
  $scope.yourName = "Name";
}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/efadal/1/